# wicked_pdf data flow issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would start content always from next page when it's breaking between pages.

Example - I have list of photos which i am exporting to pdf.
While listing some photos are cutting in two parts first is coming in one page and remaining coming on other page so how we start photo which is breaking in two part should always display from starting of the page

Answer (score 2):

```
.nobreak {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

/* http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=9#c21 */

Big thanks to Unixmonkey